# IO: do Spirits deal damage to hero without releasing its life energy in a burst during initiation?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I've been playing **IO (guradian wisp)** for a while. Recently I visited *playdota.com* and I was quite confused when I found out the mechanism behind its skill ***Spirits***:

- **Io summons 5 ancient Spirits over the course of 4 seconds; the
  Spirits dance around Io in a circle to protect him. If an enemy hero
  moves close enough to touch a Spirit, the Spirit releases its life
  energy in a burst, damaging all enemies in a 300 area of effect. Non
  hero units only take minor damage upon touching a spirit and do not
  cause them to explode.**

I remember **initiating the spirits** when an enemy was quite close to me but

had I actually **dealt any damage to the enemy before the 5 spirits were all summoned**?

During the 4seconds initiation/summoning time, no spirit seems to "release its life energy in a burst" when encounters an enemy hero.

Comment: strange. the spirits should blast immediately after they spawn. normally you do not have to wait for all spirits to be created. maybe you did not hit the hero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as the spirit starts hurling around IO, if it hits a hero, it WILL explode and cause damage.